# JQuery selectors within if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

As for context, in my page when i click on a tag it filters out and shows the posts corresponding to the clicked tag, from here i need to handle pagination to go to the next bunch of posts.

But I'm struggling with the javascript `if` statement here with jQuery, where i don't manage to differentiate the click on tag and the click on the next button to go to next page.

On top of that whereas i click on the tag or the next button i need to always grab the same variables `$clickTag`,`$catName`,`$page`

`$clickTag` value changes only if I click on the tag Name and

`$page` value changes only if i click on the next button

In my current situation the first part is working properly `if` when clicking on a tag but the second part `else` doesn't, i want to grab the page number, but instead it grab the text and store it in the `$clickTag` variable…

```js
(function($) {
  $doc = $(document);

  $doc.ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#main');
    var $pagePosts = $container.find('article');
    var $postNav = $('nav');
    var $status = $('.ajax_tag');
    var $catName = "";
    var $name = "";
    var $page = "1";
    var $clickTag = "";

    $("a[rel='tag']").addClass("tag");
    $pagePosts.wrapAll("<span class='my_container'></span>");

    var $myContainer = $('.my_container');

    $container.on('click', "a[rel='tag'], .pagination a", function(tag) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($('.tag')) {
        $clickTag = $(tag.target).text();
        getCatName($name);
        $page = "1";
      } else {
        $clickTag = $(tag.target).text();
        getCatName($name);
        $page = parseInt($this.attr('href').replace(/\D/g, ''));
      }

      $params = {
        'tag': $clickTag,
        'cat': $catName,
        'page': $page,
      };

      get_posts($params);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <span class="my_container">
      <article id="post-4996" class="post-4996 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-mdu_news tag-dog">
        <header class="entry-header">MDU_TEST  
          <a href="http://192.168.33.10/mdu_test/mdu_news/4996" rel="bookmark">MDU – allez un petit dernier pour la route</a>
          <div id="ajax_tag">TAGS:<a href="http://192.168.33.10/tag/dog" rel="tag" class="tag">dog</a>
            <div class="MDU_TEST"></div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </article>
      <article id="post-4994" class="post-4994 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-mdu_news tag-cat tag-dog">
        <header class="entry-header">MDU_TEST  
          <a href="http://192.168.33.10/mdu_test/mdu_news/4994" rel="bookmark">MDU – vu que j’ai pas mal de tags je dois faire beaucoup de posts…</a>
          <div id="ajax_tag">TAGS:<a href="http://192.168.33.10/tag/cat" rel="tag" class="tag">cat</a>, <a href="http://192.168.33.10/tag/dog" rel="tag" class="tag">dog</a>
            <div class="MDU_TEST"></div>
          </div>
        </header>
      </article>
    </span>
    <nav class="navigation pagination" role="navigation">
      <h2 class="screen-reader-text">Posts navigation</h2>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <span class="page-numbers current">
          <span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">page </span>1
        </span>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://192.168.33.10/category/mdu_test/page/2">
          <span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">page </span>2</a>
        <a class="page-numbers" href="http://192.168.33.10/category/mdu_test/page/3"><span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">page </span>3</a>
        <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://192.168.33.10/category/mdu_test/page/2">next page</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: i cant understand whats your mean of `$('.tag')` but this statement always checks  `exp` is not `null`  type is not `undefined` and is not `false` so in your case it will returns always `true` and you never able to see `else` condition

Comment: Also, `event` is not available in `event.preventDefault();` because you named the var `tag`.

Comment: @farhadamjady, okey effectively, mistaken her but how do you check if i have effectively clicked on the link which contain the class tag in the if statement ?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden, so I fixed it by doing this below is it correct ?
`$container.on('click', "a[rel='tag'], .pagination a", function(tag,event)`

Comment: No, tag and event are the same in this context. So use `tag.preventDefault()` or rename `tag` to `event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better to check the class names of the clicked element. 
Cause when you do $`('.tag')` it checks the whole page , not just the elements inside `$container`.

Also if you would like to access the currently selected element within the function that is being passed to click event , use `$(this)` instead of `$this` or `$(tag.target)`. That was the main reason why your `$page` variable was empty/undefined. Also the first parameter of this function is `event`, not the selected element. ([jquery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

```
(function($) {
  $doc = $(document);

  $doc.ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#main');
    var $pagePosts = $container.find('article');
    var $postNav = $('nav');
    var $status = $('.ajax_tag');
    var $catName = "";
    var $name = "";
    var $page = "1";
    var $clickTag = "";

    $("a[rel='tag']").addClass("tag");
    $pagePosts.wrapAll("<span class='my_container'></span>");

    var $myContainer = $('.my_container');

    $container.on('click', "a[rel='tag'], .pagination a", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ( $(this).hasClass('tag') ) {
        $clickTag = $(this).text();
        //getCatName($name);
        $page = "1";
      } else {
        $clickTag = $(this).text();
        //getCatName($name);
        $page = parseInt($(this).attr('href').replace(/\D/g, ''));
      }

      $params = {
        'tag': $clickTag,
        'cat': $catName,
        'page': $page,
      };

      console.log($params)

      //get_posts($params);
    });
  });
```

Comment: not sure to get your point here, to select a class in jQuery you do something like that `$('.myclassname')`, is there a different way?

Comment: No your selector was ok, it's just the way how you tried to distinguish the elements. So since you already had both of these elements covered by the `"a[rel='tag'], .pagination a"` selector , the other thing you had to do is to check whether the element contains '.tag' class or not. Cause this is one of the characteristics that defines the '.tag' element type in your case.

Comment: yes, this is exactly where i'm struggling, i can't figure out how.
sorry looking at your code now.

Comment: have you tried the above code? is it still not working ?

Comment: Now having issue with the `function(event){}`
if i do this then it complains that tag doesn't exist for `(tag.target).text`
`function(event) {`
I tried `($(this).target).text` but it doesn't grab the text.

And if i do this below the `event.preventDefault` doesn't work anymore
`function(tag,event) {`

Comment: simply change `$clickTag = $(tag.target).text();` to `$clickTag = $(this).text();` I've updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132976/discussion-between-matthieu-ducorps-and-alexus).

Comment: the `event.preventDefault()` isn't working cause you mixed up the function parameters.It's  `function(event, tag)`. But it's not required cause you can always access the selected element within the function body with `$(this)`.

Comment: ah ok understand, but now strangly if i click on tag it loads properly and click next it update properly my parameters but if i click on another tag, it doesn't update the $clickTag value and keep the previous one, so basically click on tag + next is ok but click on tag + click on tag doesn't work it like as soon as i have clicked on a tag it's only expecting me to click on anything but a tag…

Comment: Anyway it's a different issue thanks a lot @Alexus for you great help this specific issue is fixed !